# AvatarImageView won't render an image in Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to get the AvatarImageView https://github.com/ayushn21/AvatarImageView library to work and am having issues. I'm sure this is something simple. I'm new to swift.

I'm simply trying to make it display initials in an image. I've created a UIImageView in the storyboard that I've set with a custom class of "AvatarImageView". This is a swift file for the cell inside a tableView.

The directions here have additional info beyond the library on github: https://www.sitepoint.com/sourcehunt-swift-edition-march-2017/

It builds fine but the error I receive is "Unknown class AvatarImageView in Interface Builder file."

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple. Just can't figure this one out. Just displaying an image works fine. Everything else works.

```
 import UIKit
 import AvatarImageView

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var photo: AvatarImageView!

            struct MyUser: AvatarImageViewDataSource {
            var name = "Han Solo"
            }
            struct AvatarConfig: AvatarImageViewConfiguration {
                var shape: Shape = .square
            }

            photo.configuration = AvatarConfig()
            photo.dataSource = MyUser()


    func configureCell(text1:String?, text2:String?, text3:String?, text4:String?) {
        name.text = text1
        office.text = text2
        party.text = text3

        struct MyUser: AvatarImageViewDataSource {
            var name = "Han Solo"
        }
        struct AvatarConfig: AvatarImageViewConfiguration {
            var shape: Shape = .square
        }

        photo.configuration = AvatarConfig()
        photo.dataSource = MyUser()

        }
}
```